# Rails 4 polymorphic association has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to use `has_many` and `polymorphic` association in Rails 4?

Below is my `booth` model

```
has_many :chat, as: :chattable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :chat
```

Below is my `chat` model

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :from_user, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :to_user, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :chattable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I can't seem to retrieve `chattable` in my booth controller and views

I've tried

```
@booth.chat
```

but it says it's undefined method

Booths controller

```
class BoothsController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_booth, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :about, :products, :literature, :partners, :presentations, :contact, :videos]
    before_action :sidebar_menu

    layout "users"

    def index
        @booths = Booth.all
    end

    def show
        @booth.build_chats
        hide_sidebar 'hide-sidebar'
        @menu_items << [edit_booth_path(@booth), "Edit this booth"]
        add_sidebar_menu ["Directory", "home"], "home-nav", 
            [[hall_visit_path(@booth.hall), "Visit hall"]], false
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end

    def new
        @booth = Booth.new
        @booth.build_uploaded_file
    end

    def edit
        @menu_items << [booth_path(@booth), "Show this booth"]
        @booth.build_uploaded_file unless @booth.uploaded_file
    end

    def create
        @booth = Booth.new(booth_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @booth.save
            format.html { redirect_to @booth, notice: 'Booth was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @booth }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @booth.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
    end

    def update
        if params[:booth][:uploaded_file_attributes][:assets].blank?
            params[:booth].delete(:uploaded_file_attributes)
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          if @booth.update(booth_params)
            sync_update @booth
            format.html { redirect_to @booth, notice: 'Booth was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @booth.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
    end

      def destroy
        @booth.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to booths_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end


    def about
        render layout: false
    end

    def products
        render layout: false
    end

    def literature
        render layout: false
    end

    def partners
        render layout: false
    end

    def presentations
        render layout: false
    end

    def contact
        render layout: false
    end

    def videos
        render layout: false
    end

    def chat_widget

    end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_booth
          @booth = Booth.find(params[:id])
          uploaded_file_url(@booth)
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def booth_params
          params.require(:booth).permit(:name, :company_website, :social_media, :contact_info, :email, :about_us, :greeting_type, :event_id, :public_chat, :twitter_roll, :twitter_hash_tag, :survey_url, :prize_giveaway_description, :newsletter_description, :greeting_image_id, :greeting_audio_id, :greeting_video_id, :greeting_virtual_id, :user_id, :booth_package, :display_mode, :greeting_video,
            :facebook_url, :linkedin_url, :twitter_url, :top_message, :template_id, :hall_id, uploaded_file_attributes: [:assets])
        end

        def uploaded_file_url(booth)
            @booth_logo_url = booth.uploaded_file.assets.url if booth.uploaded_file
        end

        def sidebar_menu
            super ["Booths", "suitcase"], "booth-nav", [[booths_path, "List booths"], [new_booth_path, "Create a booth"]], true
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is in your `booth` model:

```
has_many :chat, as: :chattable, dependent: :destroy
```

Make sure to use plural `chats` when you use `has_many`.  Try replacing that line with:

```
has_many :chats, as: :chattable, dependent: :destroy
```

Then you'd reference booth's chats by: `@booth.chats`.

Comment: Thanks, would you have to do `@booth.build_chats` in the booths controller aswell?

Comment: also when I try to do `= sync partial: 'chat_widget', resource: @booth.chats` in the view I'm getting `undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0xb2dd7f8>`

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper, yes you'd have to do that for the association to be built.  I see your other comment while I'm writing this, so please post your controller code as well.  We might also need to look at your form code if the problem is not in the controller.

Comment: thank you very much. I've updated with Booths controller that I have

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper, I see only two minor changes in your controller.  All you need to do is replace `@booth.build_chats` with `@booth.chats.build` and add `@booth.chats.build` in your `new` action after `@booth = Booth.new`.  Please let me know if you need me to update the answer for this.

Comment: I'm still getting `undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0xb2dd7f8>` could this be due to the `sync` gem issue including partial in the view?

Comment: Your error trace would be helpful here, it will let us know the source of the problem.  Please add that to your question.

Comment: I just ended up putting through just `@booth` instead of `@booth.chats` and it's working now. Could this be the right solution? Also there isn't much in stack trace but that error failing straight after the controller in the view